# How is it that C# is able to copy the mem of a struct but not able to test for equality?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, operators

I can assign one struct's value to another and the memory gets copied automatically.  But if I want to test whether two structs contain the same data (as if I had just done an assignment), I have to explicitly code it.  Why is that?  It seems like the framework should have a default implementation of operator == for structs.

Comment: Subjective. The designers chose it for some reason. Might be better to discuss on programmers

Comment: For all I know, there is a solid technical reason for the way it works.  And I would not be surprised if that is the case.  I'm trying to find that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework has a default `Equals` implementation. The `==` operator is a C# feature that you must implement yourself, using `Equals` if you wish.

Comment: Doesn't `Equals` default to calling `object.ReferenceEquals`?  That wouldn't be very useful for a `struct`.

Comment: No. System.ValueType defines an overload that is implemented internally inside the CLR. It does a deep comparison.

Comment: I didn't even think about trying that.  Thanks.  Scott, he beat you by a minute, but thanks for your response as well.

Answer (score 6):

The default implementation of `ValueType.Equals` does exactly what you want. So if you do:

```
s1 = ...;
s2 = ...;
s1.Equals(s2);
```

The call to "Equals" will do the automatic deep comparison you are looking for.

In general, C# tends to favor not using overloaded operators, which is probably why it doesn't implement the operator.

Also, philosophically, C# tends to shy away from implicit behavior, including things like implicit generation of methods.

Comment: I'd also add that any reference types within the stuct will have their Equals method called in the "deep comparison".

Answer (score -2):

If you have the execute native code permission, just call `memcmp`:

```
static class memcmpsig<T> where T : struct
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(ref T left, ref T right, UIntPtr count);
}

static class CompareExtension
{
    int CompareTo<T>(this T left, T right) { return memcmpsig<T>::memcmp(left, right, Marshal::SizeOf(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: That's overkill. It will impress your peers though :-)

Comment: No need, the default `ValueType.Equals` method is optimised to use `memcmp` in some situations anyway. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2008/09/01/magic-behind-valuetype-equals.aspx

Comment: However that optimization could be considered a bug, as in the example in that blog entry.  For me, ValueType.Equals was very slow.  I'm assuming that my type did not meet the criteria for optimization.

Comment: @Fantius: From the question "two structs contain the same data (as if I had just done an assignment)".  An assignment should not be storing -0.0 when the source was +0.0.